# Ignore T When Casting to a Generic

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to cut out some additional calls and I'm making my 5 minute problem a 30 minute problem. Is there a way to cast an object without knowing its generic type? In the code below, I would like to make `Complete<T, T2>` simply `Complete<T2>`.

```
public void Complete<T, T2>(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args) 
    where T2 : new()
{
    ServiceContainer<T, T2> callback = (ServiceContainer<T, T2>)args.Result;
    StateManager.BackgroundWorker result = (StateManager.BackgroundWorker)sender;
    callback.func(result.state, callback.response);
}
```

So I would like it to look something like this:

```
public void Complete<T2>(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args) 
    where T2 : new()
{
    ServiceContainer<object, T2> callback = (ServiceContainer<object, T2>)args.Result;
    StateManager.BackgroundWorker result = (StateManager.BackgroundWorker)sender;
    callback.func(result.state, callback.response);
}
```

Comment: I suppose the easiest way would be just recreate `ServiceContainer<object, T2>` as new object and pass `args.Result` there with cast. But if it doesn't have public constructor that allows to do that, then it won't work

Comment: I wonder if you can use `dynamic` in this case. Try this: `dynamic callback = args.Result;`

Comment: @YacoubMassad I forgot about the old dynamic. It does in fact work in this case. Please add your response as an answer.

Comment: It's interesting that dynamic works . I suppose it goes through reflection that allows such downcast to object that is nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Dynamic Language Runtime like this:

```
public void Complete<T2>(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args) 
    where T2 : new()
{
    dynamic callback = args.Result;
    dynamic result = sender;
    callback.func(result.state, callback.response);
}
```

If you don't use `T2` in the method (as it appears to be in your example), you can remove it and make your method non-generic.

Comment: If you going `dynamic` route you don't even need cast - just use `dynamic` all the way...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, you mean for the `result` variable, right?

Comment: yes... `callback.func` will be bound at run-time anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You simply won't be able to do that, unless the value in `args.Result` has `object` as its first generic argument.

You can't cast a type to a type that you don't know, by definition, because what casting is is explicitly telling the compiler what the type of that object should be treated as *at compile time*.